# Using Open Document and webServices

Tags: excel, tomcat, business-objects, vba

Coming from this question : [BO 4.X Webi download report from excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495980/bo-4-x-webi-download-report-from-excel/33503454#33503454)

I've started to create a VBA macro sending HTTP request to BO server, my goal being to get a report in Excel format (Using webservices or converting the incoming HTML of OpenDocument).

Problem is I can't get Logon token. I end up having a 404 tomcat error.

Does anybody have a clearer vision of what would the problem be ?

Below my suppositions :

- Wrong HTTP request (though I checked URL, header and body plenty of time)
- I can't use restFUL webservices with BO being installed on a Tomcat Server. Sources : http://bihappyblog.com/2012/11/05/businessobjects-4-0-restful-web-service-proxy/ - https://scn.sap.com/thread/3743867

Note : Though the Javascript workaround of the first link looks interesting, I'd like to avoid implementing additionnal unsupported layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you indicated, the Tomcat application server (or whichever appserver you selected to deploy the BOE app) cannot be used for the REST SDK.

The REST SDK is only available on the WACS server, which usually runs on the same server as the rest of your BI deployment, on port 6405. Keep in mind that this si the default setup; your environment may very depending on how it was set up.

*FYI: the WACS server is nothing more than a slimmed down, embedded version of Tomcat.*

If you'd like an easy way to test your REST calls, try a tool such as [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) (available for free, requires Chrome).

Comment: I do use Postman :) 

So you mean I sould be able to query WS function anyway an there is a problem in the way I'm calling it right ? (like for instance the port number)

Comment: You'll need to update your existing query and include more detail about your code in order to find the exact cause of the errors

Comment: I solved it. For the records and beginers like me, I connected from my browser to CMC, clicked "Application" ==> "RESTful Web Service" ==> and there was the WS URL.